# Simple variogram in R, understanding gstat::variogram() and object gstat

Tags: r, gstat, covariogram

I have a `data.frame` in R whose variables represent locations and whose observations are measures of a certain variable in those locations. I want to measure the decay of dependence for certain locations depending on distance, so the variogram comes particularly useful for my studies.

I am trying to use `gstat` library but I am a bit confused about certain parameters. As far as I understand the (empirical) variogram should only need as basic data:

1. The locations of the variables
2. Observations for these variables

And then other parameters like maximun distance, directions, ...

Now, `gstat::variogram()` function requires as first input an **object of class gstat**. Checking the documentation of function `gstat()` I see that it outputs an object of this class, but this function requires a `formula` argument, which is described as:

> formula that defines the dependent variable as a linear model of independent variables; suppose the dependent variable has name z, for ordinary and simple kriging use the formula z~1; for simple kriging also define beta (see below); for universal kriging, suppose z is linearly dependent on x and y, use the formula z~x+y

Could someone explain me what this formula is for?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
methods(variogram)
```

and you'll see that gstat has several methods for variogram, one requiring a gstat object as first argument.

Given a data.frame, the easiest is to use the formula method:

```
variogram(z~1, ~x+y, data)
```

which specifies that in `data`, `z` is the observed variable of interest, `~1` specifies a constant mean model, `~x+y` specify that the coordinates are found in columns `x` and `y` of `data`.